# Styling Checkbox with CSS (further help needed)

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to implement Checkbox Four as demonstrated on this site: http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css-style-checkboxes/

I want to modify this checkbox by adding the red colored text 'N' when unchecked, and blue colored text 'Y' when checked.

The code I have so far is:

```
input[type=checkbox] 
{
    visibility: hidden;
} 


.checkboxFour 
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: -30px 160px;

    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.checkboxFour label 
{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1;

    background: #333;

    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #CC0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it via psuedo-elements

may be like this :))

```
.checkboxFour  label:before {
    content:'N';
    color:red;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkboxFour input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content:'Y';
    color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E67n6/8/

Comment: That adds a red N to the checkbox, if I add a label:after and modify that to display a Y, will I have to convert from the before to after somewhere else in the code?
Edit: Kidding, I saw your link. Thank you